# Elasticsearch, Searching by extra field in logging

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elastic-apm

I'm using Elasticsearch with `elastic-apm==6.19.0` configured for Django. After logging an error message like

```
logger.exception(
    custom_logging_message,
    exc_info=True,
    extra={
        'status_code': status_code
    },
)
```

I can indeed observe the error containing `custom_logging_message` in Kibana. In Elasticsearch, I can even use Query DSL to view the document which was created by the above logging event. It also holds the data which was passed to the logger using the `extra` keyword, as follows:

```
"error": {
    ...,
    "custom": {
        ...,
        "status_code": 500,
    }
}
```

So far so great, but I want to write a query which is based on one of the extra fields. Like:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "error.custom.status_code": {
        "gte": 500
      }
    }
  }
```

}

But the result is empty. I tried to figure out whether the respective field is indexed, using the following query: `GET _my_error_index/_mapping?pretty`. The result did indeed not hold the respective field under `"mappings"`. Is this the reason why I could not use it in the search query? And if so, how to I get it indexed? Is it a setting in the `elastic-apm` package?

I am very new to this topic and appreciate any help. Thank you.